# Javascript & JQuery: what's the difference between $x and x as variable declarations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript & JQuery, what's the difference between $x and x as variable declarations? 
For example, if I declare

```
var x = 5;
$x = 5;
x = 5;
```

am I just saying the same thing or is there a scope implication or am I just getting confused because I've been coding in several different languages?

Thanks,
Debbie

Comment: This is really two separate JavaScript/jQuery questions. 1) How are `x` and `$x` different as variables and 2) How does using `var` affect a variable's scope.

Comment: _"In Javascript & JQuery"_ - note that jQuery is 100% JavaScript, both the library itself and all code that uses the library, so jQuery doesn't provide different syntax (for variables or anything else).

Answer (score 12):

`x` and `$x` are simply two different variables. When it comes to naming JavaScript variables the dollar sign is just another character that has no special meaning.

Some people (including me) tend to name JS variables with a dollar-sign prefix if that variable is expected to hold a jQuery object, e.g., `var $x = $("div")`, but that is just a convention to make it easier to remember what the variable is for, it makes no difference at all as far as the JS interpreter is concerned.

In the code in the question, `$x` will be a global variable not because of the `$` but because any variable not declared with the `var` statement is automatically global.

Comment: +1 to both; it seems a common convention to use $ prefixed variable names for variables that are jQuery references.  I find it helps to keep things clear.

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `$x` are two different variables. The first line declares a variable `x` and assigns it a value. The second line assigns a value to variable `$x` which, all else being equal, will be implicitly declared with global scope as long as you are not running in strict mode. The third line re-assigns to previously declared variable `x`.